# I tried to make c array that draw 8x8 chesstable.Help me please?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, chess

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  

int main()

{
    const char *chess[8][8]; //using 2 dimensional array 

    chess[0][0] = "X";
    chess[0][2] = "X";
    chess[0][4] = "X";   //writing values step by step
    chess[0][6] = "X";


    chess[1][1] = "X";
    chess[1][3] = "X"; //same
    chess[1][5] = "X";
    chess[1][7] = "X";

    chess[2][0] = "X";
    chess[2][2] = "X";// same
    chess[2][4] = "X";
    chess[2][6] = "X";

    chess[3][1] = "X";
    chess[3][3] = "X";
    chess[3][5] = "X";
    chess[3][7] = "X";

    chess[4][0] = "X";
    chess[4][2] = "X";
    chess[4][4] = "X";  // same
    chess[4][6] = "X";

    chess[5][1] = "X";
    chess[5][3] = "X";
    chess[5][5] = "X";  // same
    chess[5][7] = "X";

    chess[6][0] = "X";
    chess[6][2] = "X";
    chess[6][4] = "X";  //same
    chess[6][6] = "X";

    chess[7][1] = "X";
    chess[7][3] = "X";  //same
    chess[7][5] = "X";
    chess[7][7] = "X";

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) //printing out array
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c",  &chess[i][j]); //same
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");  //same
    return 0;  


}
```

Comment: You have two problems. You're using the wrong format specifier (change the `printf` statement to `printf("%s", chess[i][j]);`). Also, you're accessing uninitialized values. Initialize the entire 2-D array to `" "` and then change the specified values to `"X"`. Also, you want `printf("\n");` after the inner `for` loop.

Comment: What's the question? Try to add 'printf("\n");' at the end of outer loop.

Comment: After using %s i get          ·O╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠0{╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠0{

Comment: @BatuhanGöbekli - yes, because your current code access memory not assigned to you. In other words - your code have undefined behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can spot five problems:

1) Wrong type:

This

```
const char *chess[8][8];
```

is 64 char-pointers but you probably want 64 chars, like

```
const char chess[8][8];
```

2) Initializing with string instead of char

Here

```
chess[0][0] = "X";
```

you use string for initialization but probably want a char, like

```
chess[0][0] = 'X'; // single ' instead of double "
```

3) You don't initialize the full array

Some of the array elements, e.g. [0][1], are uninitialized. So when you print them in the loop, you read the uninitialized value.

See the end of this answer for a more compact way of initializing the board.

4) Wrong argument for printing

Here

```
printf("%c",  &chess[i][j]);
```

you take the address of the char. That is wrong - simply do:

```
printf("%c",  chess[i][j]);
```

5) Use of `const` for a non-const variable

Here

```
const char *chess[8][8];
```

you say that `chess` is a constant. Then you can't change it later on. Instead you want

```
char *chess[8][8];
```

So putting it all together would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  

int main()

{
    char chess[8][8]; //using 2 dimensional array 

    for(int g=0; g<8; ++g)
        for (int t=0; t<8; ++t)
            chess[g][t] = 'Z';

    chess[0][0] = 'X';
    chess[0][2] = 'X';
    chess[0][4] = 'X';   //writing values step by step
    chess[0][6] = 'X';


    chess[1][1] = 'X';
    chess[1][3] = 'X'; //same
    chess[1][5] = 'X';
    chess[1][7] = 'X';

    chess[2][0] = 'X';
    chess[2][2] = 'X';// same
    chess[2][4] = 'X';
    chess[2][6] = 'X';

    chess[3][1] = 'X';
    chess[3][3] = 'X';
    chess[3][5] = 'X';
    chess[3][7] = 'X';

    chess[4][0] = 'X';
    chess[4][2] = 'X';
    chess[4][4] = 'X';  // same
    chess[4][6] = 'X';

    chess[5][1] = 'X';
    chess[5][3] = 'X';
    chess[5][5] = 'X';  // same
    chess[5][7] = 'X';

    chess[6][0] = 'X';
    chess[6][2] = 'X';
    chess[6][4] = 'X';  //same
    chess[6][6] = 'X';

    chess[7][1] = 'X';
    chess[7][3] = 'X';  //same
    chess[7][5] = 'X';
    chess[7][7] = 'X';

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) //printing out array
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c",  chess[i][j]); //same
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    //system("pause");  //same
    return 0;  
}
```

Output:

```
XZXZXZXZ
ZXZXZXZX
XZXZXZXZ
ZXZXZXZX
XZXZXZXZ
ZXZXZXZX
XZXZXZXZ
ZXZXZXZX
```

For a more compact way of initializing, you could do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  

int main()

{
    char chess[8][8]; //using 2 dimensional array 

    for(int g=0; g<8; ++g)
        for (int t=0; t<8; ++t)
        {
            if (t % 2 == g % 2)
                chess[g][t] = 'X';
            else
                chess[g][t] = 'Z';
        }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) //printing out array
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c",  chess[i][j]); //same
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    //system("pause");  //same
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I think that (1) and (2) are not errors themselves. OP wants to use a C string, not chars.

Comment: Also (5) is a not a problem as well. `const char *` is the type for a C string.

Comment: @EliSadoff - Well, in principle you could be right. But you don't want to print a chess board using strings. That would be odd.

Comment: It seems to me at least that OP set it up to be using strings. While that might not be the best choice, I don't think it's inherently wrong.

Comment: @EliSadoff - Well, to me it does seem that OP wants chars. So under the assumption that OP wants chars, (5) is a problem.

Comment: They might well be strings as posted. The Queen's Bishop and King's Bishop might be named `"QB"` and `"KB"` to narrate the moves. Although I see you were acccepted.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Yes, they could. My answer is assuming that OP wanted `char` based on the way of printing. If OP really wants strings my answer is useless and candidate for delete.

Comment: It was a good guess, so my UV as the OP liked it. Of course you would not sensibly work with strings for the play itself, only as information.